# How to programmatically fetch a file from iOS?

Tags: ios

Our application runs on Android and iOS. While it is running, it creates a few files and stores them locally.

I am now developing a desktop application that fetches the files from the usb-connected device and loads the content in our UI.

On Android, I could spawn "adb" to get the list of files and to fetch a specific file.

I am wondering how I can do something similar for an iOS device that is attached to a Mac. Are there any programmatic APIs on Mac? Or, is there is a command line tool similar to adb that I could use? Regards.